# Need to track the website or link from which users landing on our web pages  - jS or PHP Coding

Tags: php, javascript, tracking, landing-page

We have three fare traffic  websites ( for three different brand products ) and all are well  serving our internet marketing needs.  recently , we are planned to  promote each website on  other two websites to increase our traffic to each other there by reducing Google Ads cost to promote website.  Our plan is working well, the only thing it worries us is tracking the traffic source. For  googl adwords (CPC) and our ads on other websites lands at same Landing Page (Lead generation Page ) and hence we are facing difficult analyse the traffic and big problem is that our management want to access this information in readable form .

Of-course , google analytic s will serve this information but for that we need to log in account and then we should take report or do some analysis .

but what we are looking is something like IP Capturing .So if any persona comes from webiste page ( eg www.xyz.com/read.html  if  they click our ad on the site page and lands on to our website . we have to capture the web link or website from which user landed to our webiste .

Answer (score 1):

**You can program Google Analytics to send a PDF report trough email. This is the easiest and probably most effective way of doing it.**

Or you can check if your server has awstats or if you can install it. Awstats produces reports from server logs, and logs refer urls.

Or you can use Piwik for your stats and create a public widget.

Probably what you are looking is **a way is to access the refer trough a server side language,** count the visits and generate a page with a URL with that information.

Most server side programming languages can access the refer url, so you can have a server side script do something with it, like create a url that is a report.

In PHP the refer is stored in the variable: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

In Python:

```
import os
referurl = os.getenv('HTTP_REFERER')
```

So with this solution all you need is a script that creates a counter by URL.

Comment: its worked fine in PHP . thank you very much &  I need to be able to get the HTTP-REFERER of an
HTML page. Is it possible to do it with a JavaScript applet includedin the page itself?

Comment: Yes, var urlRefPage =  document.referrer;

Comment: thnks it works :)   this reduced my work a lot